# Show tab content on top when swiping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a swipable tab which is created using Slick Js. Mainly im trying to use this on phone so the users can swipe through the content...

The problem is that on each tab there are content. Lets say from the first tab, i scroll down and move to the next 2nd tab, the content starts half way from where i have scrolled down. I want to make it start from the top on each tab.

Below is what i have done so far

Codepen link https://codepen.io/livewirerules/pen/vxzPaW

**HTML**

```
<div class="sub-header ">

    <div class="swipe-tabs">
    <div class="swipe-tab">One</div>
    <div class="swipe-tab">Two</div>
    <div class="swipe-tab">Three</div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="swipe-tabs-container ">
    <div class="swipe-tab-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nibh at pretium pellentesque. In sed cursus mauris. Aenean lobortis egestas imperdiet. Sed finibus odio ex, id luctus neque lobortis at. Maecenas sodales est eget tortor efficitur semper. Duis porttitor ligula tempus sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Etiam at arcu ullamcorper, finibus nibh vitae, iaculis justo. Praesent vitae sem sollicitudin, tristique turpis in, fringilla nisi. Etiam ac diam lectus. </div>
    <div class="swipe-tab-content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nibh at pretium pellentesque. In sed cursus mauris. Aenean lobortis egestas imperdiet. Sed finibus odio ex, id luctus neque lobortis at. Maecenas sodales est eget tortor efficitur semper. Duis porttitor ligula tempus sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Etiam at arcu ullamcorper, finibus nibh vitae, iaculis justo. Praesent vitae sem sollicitudin, tristique turpis in, fringilla nisi. Etiam ac diam lectus.

Etiam eu lobortis arcu. Vestibulum dolor augue, commodo nec nisl ultrices, fermentum lobortis dui. Morbi quis odio ante. Phasellus eleifend justo vitae nisl imperdiet, volutpat sagittis mi tincidunt. Nunc pharetra ipsum ac mi cursus vestibulum cursus at lectus. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas et tellus et justo tempor sollicitudin. Praesent maximus lacinia justo vitae ornare.

Sed aliquet id sapien eget posuere. In urna nunc, mollis eget diam sit amet, luctus laoreet mi. In cursus lectus et quam gravida, nec vulputate risus vulputate. Duis sit amet leo pellentesque, interdum erat eu, suscipit lorem. Nulla facilisi. Sed dignissim faucibus diam, at maximus urna vulputate eu. Aliquam mi metus, suscipit a commodo vehicula, semper eu sapien. Suspendisse in nunc eget tortor iaculis semper. Sed non purus faucibus, consequat dolor vel, eleifend ante. Morbi et ex pharetra tellus auctor sagittis. Praesent sollicitudin mi ut tempus commodo. Vestibulum ornare libero eget ex porta elementum. Curabitur est felis, viverra quis nisl non, maximus tempus ante. 
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nibh at pretium pellentesque. In sed cursus mauris. Aenean lobortis egestas imperdiet. Sed finibus odio ex, id luctus neque lobortis at. Maecenas sodales est eget tortor efficitur semper. Duis porttitor ligula tempus sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Etiam at arcu ullamcorper, finibus nibh vitae, iaculis justo. Praesent vitae sem sollicitudin, tristique turpis in, fringilla nisi. Etiam ac diam lectus.

Etiam eu lobortis arcu. Vestibulum dolor augue, commodo nec nisl ultrices, fermentum lobortis dui. Morbi quis odio ante. Phasellus eleifend justo vitae nisl imperdiet, volutpat sagittis mi tincidunt. Nunc pharetra ipsum ac mi cursus vestibulum cursus at lectus. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas et tellus et justo tempor sollicitudin. Praesent maximus lacinia justo vitae ornare.

Sed aliquet id sapien eget posuere. In urna nunc, mollis eget diam sit amet, luctus laoreet mi. In cursus lectus et quam gravida, nec vulputate risus vulputate. Duis sit amet leo pellentesque, interdum erat eu, suscipit lorem. Nulla facilisi. Sed dignissim faucibus diam, at maximus urna vulputate eu. Aliquam mi metus, suscipit a commodo vehicula, semper eu sapien. Suspendisse in nunc eget tortor iaculis semper. Sed non purus faucibus, consequat dolor vel, eleifend ante. Morbi et ex pharetra tellus auctor sagittis. Praesent sollicitudin mi ut tempus commodo. Vestibulum ornare libero eget ex porta elementum. Curabitur est felis, viverra quis nisl non, maximus tempus ante. </div>
    <div class="swipe-tab-content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempor nibh at pretium pellentesque. In sed cursus mauris. Aenean lobortis egestas imperdiet. Sed finibus odio ex, id luctus neque lobortis at. Maecenas sodales est eget tortor efficitur semper. Duis porttitor ligula tempus sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Etiam at arcu ullamcorper, finibus nibh vitae, iaculis justo. Praesent vitae sem sollicitudin, tristique turpis in, fringilla nisi. Etiam ac diam lectus.

Etiam eu lobortis arcu. Vestibulum dolor augue, commodo nec nisl ultrices, fermentum lobortis dui. Morbi quis odio ante. Phasellus eleifend justo vitae nisl imperdiet, volutpat sagittis mi tincidunt. Nunc pharetra ipsum ac mi cursus vestibulum cursus at lectus. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas et tellus et justo tempor sollicitudin. Praesent maximus lacinia justo vitae ornare.

Sed aliquet id sapien eget posuere. In urna nunc, mollis eget diam sit amet, luctus laoreet mi. In cursus lectus et quam gravida, nec vulputate risus vulputate. Duis sit amet leo pellentesque, interdum erat eu, suscipit lorem. Nulla facilisi. Sed dignissim faucibus diam, at maximus urna vulputate eu. Aliquam mi metus, suscipit a commodo vehicula, semper eu sapien. Suspendisse in nunc eget tortor iaculis semper. Sed non purus faucibus, consequat dolor vel, eleifend ante. Morbi et ex pharetra tellus auctor sagittis. Praesent sollicitudin mi ut tempus commodo. Vestibulum ornare libero eget ex porta elementum. Curabitur est felis, viverra quis nisl non, maximus tempus ante. </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
$swipe-tab-color: #757575;
$swipe-active-tab-color: #000;

.swipe-tab-content.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active {margin-top:50px;z-index: -99999}
.sub-header {

    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 9999999;
}

.slick-initialized {
  .swipe-tab-content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 365px;

    @media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
      min-height: 500px;
    }
  }

  .swipe-tab {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50px;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    color: $swipe-tab-color;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba($swipe-active-tab-color, 0);
    transition: all 0.5s;

    &:hover {
      color: $swipe-active-tab-color;
    }

    &.active-tab {
      border-bottom-color: $swipe-active-tab-color;
      color: $swipe-active-tab-color;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

  }
}


.main-container {
  padding: 25px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    var $swipeTabsContainer = $('.swipe-tabs'),
        $swipeTabs = $('.swipe-tab'),
        $swipeTabsContentContainer = $('.swipe-tabs-container'),
        currentIndex = 0,
        activeTabClassName = 'active-tab';

    $swipeTabsContainer.on('init', function(event, slick) {
        $swipeTabsContentContainer.removeClass('invisible');
        $swipeTabsContainer.removeClass('invisible');

        currentIndex = slick.getCurrent();
        $swipeTabs.removeClass(activeTabClassName);
        $('.swipe-tab[data-slick-index=' + currentIndex + ']').addClass(activeTabClassName);
    });

    $swipeTabsContainer.slick({
        //slidesToShow: 3.25,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        swipeToSlide: true,
        touchThreshold: 10
    });

    $swipeTabsContentContainer.slick({
        asNavFor: $swipeTabsContainer,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        swipeToSlide: true,
    draggable: false,
        touchThreshold: 10
    });


    $swipeTabs.on('click', function(event) {
        // gets index of clicked tab
        currentIndex = $(this).data('slick-index');
        $swipeTabs.removeClass(activeTabClassName);
        $('.swipe-tab[data-slick-index=' + currentIndex +']').addClass(activeTabClassName);
        $swipeTabsContainer.slick('slickGoTo', currentIndex);
        $swipeTabsContentContainer.slick('slickGoTo', currentIndex);
    });

    //initializes slick navigation tabs swipe handler
    $swipeTabsContentContainer.on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction) {
        currentIndex = $(this).slick('slickCurrentSlide');
        $swipeTabs.removeClass(activeTabClassName);
        $('.swipe-tab[data-slick-index=' + currentIndex + ']').addClass(activeTabClassName);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Slick documentation, this should do it:

```
$('.swipe-tabs').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, direction){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  });
});
```

Another possible event would be `swipe` (instead of `beforeChange`). However, I find it a bit weird having both `swipe` and `scrollTop` events at same time, as it results in a diagonal direction. See if using `afterChange` makes more sense visually.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on the slick page and type in `methods` to view all your available options.

Comment: Thanks.. But this works only once... From the first tab when i scroll down and move to the next tab it scrolls to the top, after that it doesnt move on any other tabs.. Any reason why?

Comment: You must have messed it up. Here's your updated [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZmZWz). Working every time.

Comment: I was calling the wrong class... Its working now.. Thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome. And don't worry, it's part of coding. Happy coding!